# Does Apple Music let you hear the whole song on iPhone and iPad? (instead of just 30 seconds or 1:30 of sampling)

Tags: iphone, itunes, mac, apple-music

After I started with the Apple Music 3-month trial, sometimes I search for a song on my iPhone, and I could actually hear the whole song.

So I thought Apple Music probably lets me hear the whole song for most or all of its songs, but there are other cases when I search for a song on my Macbook using iTunes, I could only hear the 30 second clip or 1.5 minute clip like before.

So what is the rule?  I could hear most (or all) the songs on iPhone and iPad for any song on iTunes Store, but not on  any Mac -- is this basically the rule for subscribers to Apple Music?

Comment: Perhaps listing links to one or two tracks will clarify whether you are seeing intentional behavior based on negotiate rights between Apple and the labels/artists or if you have a temporary issue.

Answer (score 1):

I've never had a song not play through on iOS or OS X via Apple Music. My guess is network congestion is the culprit when you don't get a full play.

Another possibility is your iTunes account is in a geographical region where Apple Music doesnt have broad coverage of the songs in Apple's total catalog. In at case, those songs that are for sale somewhere in the world, but not in your region, might have previews instead of full plays.

For me in the us, Apple Music gives me all the music I care to consume for the subscription period across all decides that are signed your Apple ID. The notorious artists like Prince simply don't show up so I haven't found a song that' soft sale but not for streaming.

Comment: I don't mean songs you purchased; I mean the ones that you didn't

Comment: @太極者無極而生 I mean all songs (thousands over a 3 month trial) all played to completion without ever "purchasing" anything. Yes - I'm purchasing a subscription now, but all songs play for me in iTunes - period. I suppose there might be some songs that are opted out/not opted in to match subscription and you still get previews. I will edit my post for clarity.

Comment: Ok, I think I get it... If you go to a Mac, use iTunes for the iTunes Store, and search for "Depeche Mode" and listen to "People are People", then it is 1:30 only of sampling.  But if you go to "My Music" and search for "Depeche Mode", it may not show up in "My Library", but you need to click on "Apple Music" in the search result box, and then it will show and if you listen there, then it is the whole song...  So it really depends "how you get to the song" in iTunes on a Mac

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Woah - that's not very intuitive. Great description of what you've found.